# IE 8 only has access to session cookies?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, internet-explorer-8

Project I'm working on gets cookies from the browser to check for certain things. In FF, Safari, or Chrome, this works fine, but in IE 8 (don't have an earlier version of IE to test and MSFT won't let me uninstall IE 8 and have a working IE 7), the only cookies it sees are the session cookies, not any of the persistent cookies (the ones found in the Temporary Internet Files). This exact same method is used elsewhere in the app, and in IE 8 when its on its own page, works fine. Only when it's contained as a small pixel on another page is when it can't seem to find the cookies. I looked at the request to see if maybe it was under a different domain, but nope, same domain. It's weird because it can see the session cookies (ones with no expiration that should expire at the end of the browser session) but nothing else.

Anyone seen anything like this before? I'll respond to any questions as soon as I can.

This is in .NET using simple Context.Request.Cookies

Comment: Using session cookies in an application that works in IE7 and IE8.

I would check your IE security settings.  Can you sniff the HTTP request using Fiddler or other HTTP sniffing tool?  That might give you more insight on what is being passed back and forth from the browser to the server.

Comment: Since I'm running the server locally, I am able to put breakpoints and look at the request itself. For some reason, the Request.Cookies collection ONLY has the session cookie which was set at the session start (pre server-side redirect). I suppose I should mention that the exact same method at the same place from the same pixel works fine, when its not coming off of a Server-Side-Redirect. It's only after the server-side redirect when it looks at the cookies that it only sees the session cookie, even though everything else about the request looks the same.

Comment: In addition, this seems to only be occuring on my IE 8, it does not seem repeatable on other machines IE 8. Re-Installing doesn't fix it.

Comment: If you need to test old IE versions check out IE Tester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the privacy policy. There are headers that you can set to allow cookies from other domains than the one shown in the address bar. Here's [the best description I've found](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx) on how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Indeed, you probably need to set a P3P policy if this is a 3rd-party cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Some spammers use 1x1 images and iframes to stuff affiliate cookies, and IE8 apparently has measures against this technique. Could you be suffering as an innocent casualty of an anti-spammer attack?

Comment: The "InPrivate Filtering" feature is off-by-default, and not likely a factor here.

Answer (score 0):

Seams a bug in IE8:
http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/369240/ie8-will-not-send-third-party-cookies-set-in-another-window-tab